# Unable to download a file/content from Azure Repositories using Terraform Data Sources (http and external)?

Tags: json, azure-devops, terraform, azure-functions, infrastructure-as-code

I am creating Azure Function Apps using Terraform. I wanted to download and pass function app settings to terraform configuration during runtime using a data block.

I have created a second Repo Called <feature/function_settings> and created a function app settings in the settings.json file.

I am trying to download the settings.json file using HTTP and external data sources. Please find below outcomes, and Help me out.

1. **Using HTTP data source:** Getting authentication error earlier. Now that issue is resolved but unable to download the file or pull the file content.
2. **Using external data sources:** I have created a file named func_settings.ps1 with the below script.

   ```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      $personalToken="PAT_Token"
      $header = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)")))}
      Write-Host "Download the file" 

      $uriGetFile = "https://dev.azure.com/<Organisaion>/<Project>/_apis/git/repositories/<Repository_Name>/items?scopePath=settings.json&download=true&versionDescriptor.version=<Branch_Name>&api-version=6.1-preview.1"
      Write-Host "Url:" $uriGetFile

      $outfile = Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing -Headers $header -Uri $uriGetFile
      $outfile | ConvertTo-json
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------


    data "external" "settings_data" { 
      program = ["powershell.exe", "${path.module}/func_settings.ps1"] 
      }

    output "func_settings" {
      value = data.external.settings_data
    }
   ```

   Getting the below outcome in the VS Code Console,

   ```
    PS D:\testfolder\Test_TF\func-dynamic-config> terraform apply
    ╷
    │ Error: Unexpected External Program Results
    │
    │   with data.external.settings_data,
    │   on outputs.tf line 43, in data "external" "settings_data":
    │   43:   program = ["powershell.exe", "${path.module}/func_settings.ps1"]
    │
    │ The data source received unexpected results after executing the program.
    │
    │ Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.
    │
    │ If the error is unclear, the output can be viewed by enabling Terraform's logging at TRACE level. Terraform documentation on logging:
    │ https://www.terraform.io/internals/debugging
    │
    │ Program: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
    │ Result Error: invalid character 'D' looking for beginning of value
   ```

   ---

The main focus is on external data sources. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got it to work with the second approach i.e. **external data sources**. The process is correct—the only problem is with the func_settings.json complex structure.

As the error says "Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values." I have not used simple key-value pairs in the settings file. So then finally i tried with the simple key-value pair JSON format like below. It worked then.

```
{
name = "test_name",
location = "test_location"
}
```

**Note:** Try to solve problems with simple thinking (code/programming/logic), then go for complex thinking.